# Autofill not populating until last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate the date and have it populate the column until the last row of data. However it doesn't seem to populate to the last line of data and I don't understand why. What is wrong with my code?

```
Sub updatedate()
lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2:F" & lastRow) = Date
Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Style = "Normal"
Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Value = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")

End Sub
```

the date in format yyyymmdd to be updated and populated on each row until last in column F

Comment: Is column F empty?

Comment: Your 3rd line is unnecessary since the 5th one overwrites it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on the line

```
lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

If you change `"F"` to `"A"` (or any other suitable column) it will work better.
The last used cell in the F column is not yet used.